# MVC ActionLink not calling controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view with an ActionLink and when clicking the link I get the "Resource not found" error.

ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create order","CreateOrder", new { StockId = Model.ID })
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateOrder(Stock stockItem, int id)
    {
        Order newOrder = CreateOrderFromStock(stockItem);

        return RedirectToAction("../Orders/Edit/", newOrder.ID);
    }
```

Why am I getting the Resource not found error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have marked your method with the `HttpPost` attribute but a link issues a GET request. Remove that attribute.

Comment: I would argue the method should indeed be a `[Post]` method given it is creating data and that the link is the issue here.

Comment: Indeed, using a GET for this leaves you open to CSRF.

Comment: @NinjaNye You are probably right - I'll extend my answer a bit later if nobody beats me to it.